# Camera LensFacing verification failed, existing cameras

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

I am trying to use the front camera to capture the pictures. But I am getting the error:-  Camera LensFacing verification failed, existing cameras.

I am also unable to get the preview of the camera as well. Here is the code :-

```
@ExperimentalPermissionsApi
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoilApi::class, ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            OP2Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    MainContent(Modifier.fillMaxSize())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@ExperimentalCoilApi
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@ExperimentalPermissionsApi
@Composable
fun MainContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val emptyImageUri = Uri.parse("file://dev/null")
    var imageUri by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyImageUri) }
    if (imageUri != emptyImageUri) {
        Box(modifier = modifier) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                painter = rememberImagePainter(imageUri),
                contentDescription = "Captured image"
            )
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                onClick = {
                    imageUri = emptyImageUri
                }
            ) {
                Text("Remove image")
            }
        }
    } else {
        CameraCapture(
            modifier = modifier,
            onImageFile = { file ->
                imageUri = file.toUri()
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}


@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    OP2Theme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

Here is the code for camera preview:-

```
@Composable
fun CameraPreview(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    scaleType: PreviewView.ScaleType = PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_CENTER,
    onUseCase: (UseCase) -> Unit = { }
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            val previewView = PreviewView(context).apply {
                this.scaleType = scaleType
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
            }
            onUseCase(
                Preview.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                    }
            )
            previewView
        }
    )
}
```

here is my code for camera capture:-

```
@ExperimentalPermissionsApi
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Composable
fun CameraCapture(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA,
    onImageFile: (File) -> Unit = { }
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Permission(
        permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        rationale = "You said you wanted a picture, so I'm going to have to ask for permission.",
        permissionNotAvailableContent = {
            Column(modifier) {
                Text("O noes! No Camera!")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        context.startActivity(
                            Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS).apply {
                                data = Uri.fromParts("package", context.packageName, null)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Open Settings")
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        Box(modifier = modifier) {
            val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
            val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
            var previewUseCase by remember { mutableStateOf<UseCase>(Preview.Builder().build()) }
            val imageCaptureUseCase by remember {
                mutableStateOf(
                    ImageCapture.Builder()
                        .setCaptureMode(CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
                        .build()
                )
            }
            Box {
                CameraPreview(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    onUseCase = {
                        previewUseCase = it
                    }
                )
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentSize()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                    onClick = {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            imageCaptureUseCase.takePicture(context.executor).let {
                                onImageFile(it)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Click!")
                }
            }
            LaunchedEffect(previewUseCase) {
                val cameraProvider = context.getCameraProvider()
                try {
                    // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them.
                    cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, previewUseCase, imageCaptureUseCase
                    )
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    Log.e("CameraCapture", "Failed to bind camera use cases", ex)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my permissions code:-

```
@ExperimentalPermissionsApi
@Composable
fun Permission(
    permission: String = android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
    rationale: String = "This permission is important for this app. Please grant the permission.",
    permissionNotAvailableContent: @Composable () -> Unit = { },
    content: @Composable () -> Unit = { }
) {
    val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(permission)
    PermissionRequired(
        permissionState = permissionState,
        permissionNotGrantedContent = {
            Rationale(
                text = rationale,
                onRequestPermission = { permissionState.launchPermissionRequest() }
            )
        },
        permissionNotAvailableContent = permissionNotAvailableContent,
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
private fun Rationale(
    text: String,
    onRequestPermission: () -> Unit
) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = { /* Don't */ },
        title = {
            Text(text = "Permission request")
        },
        text = {
            Text(text)
        },
        confirmButton = {
            Button(onClick = onRequestPermission) {
                Text("Ok")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Dependencies of camerax in Build.gradle:-

```
//Camera
def camerax_version = "1.2.1"
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-alpha03"
```

Permissions in Manifest.xml:-

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

These are the errors I am getting while using this code.:-

```
  E/CameraValidator: Camera LensFacing verification failed, existing cameras: [Camera@af090c1[id=0], Camera@743c9c0[id=1]]
    E/CameraX: The device might underreport the amount of the cameras. Finish the initialize task since we are already reaching the maximum number of retries.
    E/CameraCapture: Failed to bind camera use cases
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided camera selector unable to resolve a camera for the given use case
            at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:479)
            at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:366)
            at com.op2.files.CameraCaptureKt$CameraCapture$3$1$2.invokeSuspend(CameraCapture.kt:110)
            at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
    E/CameraCapture: Failed to bind camera use cases
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided camera selector unable to resolve a camera for the given use case
            at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:479)
            at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:366)
            at com.op2.files.CameraCaptureKt$CameraCapture$3$1$2.invokeSuspend(CameraCapture.kt:110)
            at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
    I/ViewRootImpl@9e9624a[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
    I/ViewRootImpl@9e9624a[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
    D/ImageCapture: takePictureWithNode
    E/TakePicture: Image capture failed
        androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException: Not bound to a valid Camera [ImageCapture:androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-b7455703-bb88-40b0-b3da-acfd633286f6]
            at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.sendInvalidCameraError(ImageCapture.java:1725)
            at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.takePictureWithNode(ImageCapture.java:1706)
            at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.takePicture(ImageCapture.java:918)
            at com.op2.files.ExtKt.takePicture(ext.kt:43)
            at com.op2.files.ExtKt$takePicture$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:13)
            at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.op2, PID: 5120
        androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException: Not bound to a valid Camera [ImageCapture:androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-b7455703-bb88-40b0-b3da-acfd633286f6]
            at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.sendInvalidCameraError(ImageCapture.java:1725)
            at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.takePictureWithNode(ImageCapture.java:1706)
            at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.takePicture(ImageCapture.java:918)
            at com.op2.files.ExtKt.takePicture(ext.kt:43)
            at com.op2.files.ExtKt$takePicture$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:13)
            at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
            Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@6183a1, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@f2649c6, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@2ebed87, AndroidUiDispatcher@e3d74b4]
```

Comment: Can you share the dependencies of camerax

Comment: I have added the dependencies of CameraX in Build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different versions of camerax_version use the same version.

Make these changes in build.gradle.:-

```
//Camera
def camerax_version = "1.2.1"
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:$camerax_version"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was just a minor mistake. But your answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error might be related to missing camera permission, camera configuration, or hardware issues.

To resolve the issue, you can start by checking if you have the correct camera permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file. Ensure that you have included the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

You should also check that the device you are using has a front camera. Some devices do not have a front camera, and attempting to access it will result in an error.

Comment: I am running it on physical device. I already have these permissions in Manifest file. Even the back camera is also not showing.

Comment: It is not working on other physical devices as well.